# MCAS REST API Limit issues(nextQueryFilters)

Tags: c#, logging

I am trying to collect Microsoft Defender for Cloud Activity Log using C#.
If you look at the Python example, the value of the nextQueryFilters item should be entered as a filter.
But when I run it in C# and check the test result, the items in nextQueryFilters themselves are not retrieved.
Please check if there is a problem with my code.

```
    string tenantId = "mytenantId";
    string appId = "myappId";
    string appSecret = "myappSecret";
    
    const string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
    const string MCASResourceId = "myMCASResourceId";
    
    AuthenticationContext auth = new AuthenticationContext($"{authority}/{tenantId}/");
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, appSecret);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = auth.AcquireTokenAsync(MCASResourceId, clientCredential).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    bool hasNextPage = false;
    
    do
    {
    Url = "https://url.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/activities/?filters={\"date\":{ \"gte_ndays\":1}}&isScan:True";
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Url))
    {
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    using (HttpResponseMessage respose = httpClient.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
    {
    string json = respose.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    }
    } while (hasNextPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled it in the following way. Please note.

filter = "isScan=True&sortField=created&limit=5000";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).